# Generalization of the Difference Quotients

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers, real-numbers, quotient-spaces, central-limit-theorem

Based on the geometry of the three difference quotients in calculus, it seems there should be a general form $$P(f(x + h) - f(x)) + (1 - P)(f(x) - f(x - h))\over h$$ where $0 <= P <= 1$, at least if $P$ is real.

Is there a name for this form, or any utility for it?  Can $P$ ever be a non-real complex number?

Answer (score 1):

If $p=\frac{1}{2}$ then we arrive at the central difference. I did not see the approach you propose, however such differences could be called weighted differences.